# Perform calculations in named groups of dataframes within a dataframe list, reduce the list, return list in tidyverse, R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to start from a list of 9 named dataframes (e.g. **transport_list** below), reduce them (fulljoin) to 3 dataframes based on matching dataframe prefix names (e.g. **buses_**, **speed trains_**, **bi-cycles_** etc).

Then calculate the mean value for each city within each of the 3 dataframes - basically from the years 2017 to 2019.

To finally end up with a list (e.g. **desired_output_list**) of 3 named dataframes (buses, trains, bi-cycles) each of which has the following columns (**city**, **value_mean**)

How can I do this using tidyverse/dplyr?

**NB:** The names of **prefixes** can be a single word e.g. "buses_*", or a two words with a space e.g. "speed train_*" or two words with a hyphen in between "bi-cycle_*".

**NB2:** This **suffix pattern** is constant across all dataframes in the list *_2017 to *_2019 i.e. the years to calculate the means from.

**NB3** In the real dataset I have 9 named dataframes actually 216. As well as more than 3 years 2005:2019.

```
transport_list <- list(buses_2017 = data.frame(city = c("Cambridge", "London", "Oxford", "Glasgow"),
                                                value = c(34, 41, 50, 48)),
                       
                       buses_2018 = data.frame(city = c("Cambridge", "London", "Oxford", "Glasgow"),
                                                value = c(37, 45, 60, 38)),
                       
                       buses_2019 = data.frame(city = c("Cambridge", "London", "Oxford", "Glasgow"),
                                                value = c(41, 46, 58, 35)),
                       
                       "speed trains_2017" = data.frame(city = c("Cambridge", "London", "Oxford", "Glasgow"),
                                                 value = c(48, 50, 41, 34)),
                       
                       "speed trains_2018" = data.frame(city = c("Cambridge", "London", "Oxford", "Glasgow"),
                                                 value = c(38, 45, 12, 15)),
                       
                       "speed trains_2019" = data.frame(city = c("Cambridge", "London", "Oxford", "Glasgow"),
                                                 value = c(50, 48, 51, 22)),

                       "bi-cycles_2017" = data.frame(city = c("Cambridge", "London", "Oxford", "Glasgow"),
                                                   value = c(148, 150, 141, 134)),
                       
                       "bi-cycles_2018" = data.frame(city = c("Cambridge", "London", "Oxford", "Glasgow"),
                                                   value = c(380, 450, 120, 150)),
                       
                       "bi-cycles_2019" = data.frame(city = c("Cambridge", "London", "Oxford", "Glasgow"),
                                                   value = c(500, 480, 510, 220  )))

### Starting from a list of 9 named dataframes, reduce them (fulljoin) to 3 dataframes based on matching dataframe prefix names (e.g. buses_*, trains_*, bi-cycles_* etc). Then calculate the mean value for each city within each of the 3 dataframes. To finally end up with a list of 3 named dataframes (buses, trains, bi-cycles) each of which has the following columns (city, value_mean)

transport_list %>%
  reduce(full_join) %>%  
  group_by(city) %>% 
  summarise(mean(value)) %>% 
  arrange(city)

####### Desired output should look like this list ##########

desired_output_list <- list(buses = data.frame(city = c("Cambridge", "London", "Oxford", "Glasgow"),
                                               mean_value = c(37.333, 44, 56, 43.667)),
                       
                       trains = data.frame(city = c("Cambridge", "London", "Oxford", "Glasgow"),
                                                mean_value = c(45.333, 47.667, 34.667, 23.667)),
                       
                       "bi-cycles" = data.frame(city = c("Cambridge", "London", "Oxford", "Glasgow"),
                                                   mean_value = c(342.667, 360, 257, 168)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the list by their name and use `map` to apply the same function to each list.

```
library(tidyverse)

split(transport_list, sub('_\\d+', '', names(transport_list))) %>%
  map(~.x %>%
        reduce(full_join) %>%  
        group_by(city) %>% 
        summarise(value = mean(value)) %>% 
        arrange(city))

#$`bi-cycles`
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  city      value
#  <chr>     <dbl>
#1 Cambridge  343.
#2 Glasgow    168 
#3 London     360 
#4 Oxford     257 

#$buses
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  city      value
#  <chr>     <dbl>
#1 Cambridge  37.3
#2 Glasgow    40.3
#3 London     44  
#4 Oxford     56  

#$`speed trains`
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  city      value
#  <chr>     <dbl>
#1 Cambridge  45.3
#2 Glasgow    23.7
#3 London     47.7
#4 Oxford     34.7
```

---

This can be translated in base R as -

```
lapply(split(transport_list, sub('_\\d+', '', names(transport_list))), function(x) {
  aggregate(value ~ city, Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE), x), mean)
})
```